# Node.js streams giving different results on Windows and Linux

Tags: node.js, stream, request, streaming, node-request

I'm reading a string stream using `http.request` and the following (simplified) code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: XXXX,
    port: XXXX,
    path: XXXX,
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 15000,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
    }
};

node.request = http.request(options, function (response)
{
    response.on('data', function (chunk)
    {
        console.log("Length: " + chunk.byteLength);
    });
});
```

- If I run this code on a Linux machine, the `byteLength` for each chunk is always more or less the same, around `3000`.
- If I run this code on a Windows machine, the `byteLength` for each chunk varies. The first chunk is around `3000` and the next ones are around `1500`.

I know that the origin, answers with fragments of `3000` every x seconds. Linux receives the entire fragment, and it seems that on Windows the fragment is splitted (it looks like the `onData` event is fired two times)

Are there any differences between the Linux and Windows versions for this library? Does someone know what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but: make sure your program works whether the average chunk is 3000, 1500, or 5 bytes.  You cannot rely on any specific behavior here, so your best bet is to read in data until you have a full "message" (whatever that is in your case) and then process that message.

Comment: It does. I just want to know why I get different stream response on Windows and Linux.